# How to migrate WordPress from live to local?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, xampp, localhost

Its common to find explanations on how to migrate WordPress sites from local to live, but what about the opposite? I have a live website and i would like to run it in XAMPP, how can i download the database and then upload it locally? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broad question that I'm sure some googling could answer quickly but it's really just the opposite of uploading.  If your hosting company uses cpanel.  Just go to your cpanel and then find phpmyadmin.  From phpmyadmin you can just download your DB by clicking on the db that your wordpress site uses.  Then click on Export and export the SQL.  Next go to your wordpress site and export any theme settings if your theme has them.  Then export your wordpress site to a zip file the same way you would import.  Once you have your DB, theme settings and wordpress site exported you can just upload them to your local setup just like you are uploading them to a live server.

Also there are plenty of backup plugins that backup everything in to a zip including yor wordpress db.  You can then unzip and upload your files to your localhost with xampp.

Anything your not sure of I'm sure you can find more info on google going through the steps I've listed.